# text boundary in Microsoft Word

Tags: text, ms-word, boundary

I have a problem with text boundary in Microsoft Word. It shows around the paragraph instead of the whole page.

[image: See this reference.]
Please could anyone help me to view this as a page boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you are using Word 2013 or later. This is how the text boundaries now display. There is no option to make them display as they did in previous versions.

If you don't like it make your feelings known to Microsoft via User Voice.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in "Page Layout" to optimize your Margins. I assume, this is what you wanted. Else, please share more details.

Comment: I don't see any help on this. could you detail of what you have found?

Comment: Your problem is unclear. I assume, you need to add a page boundary. Check the option Page Layout -> Margins -> Custom margins -> Layout Tab -> Borders. There you can add page boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

The following is for Word 2013 - 2016

1. Select **Design** in Ribbon Menu
2. Click **Page Borders**
3. In **Borders and Shadow** dialog box

   - Choose **Box**, **Shadow**, **3D**, or **Custom** type
   - Choose line **style**
   - Choose **Color** and **Width**
   - And finally select **Whole Document** in **Apply To** section

Answer (score -1):

this is the display for office 2013 and 2016. if you use version 2010, you will get the whole page. enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLQgL.png)

Comment: "Enter image description", please do so with enough details that your answer still makes helpful sense when the link decays.